# Proof Explanation. Interior of $A$ is $\mathring A=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:x_1\lt 0,x_2\gt 0\}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

This is from my notes in class. I don't get the parts in blue. Can you explain/elaborate on that, please?
But first, I don't understand why we can define such $\varepsilon$ in a way that $B(x,\varepsilon)$ can fit into $A$. How do we determine that? If you can be explicit I'll appreciate that.

Given $A=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:x_1\lt 0,x_2\ge 0\}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert=\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$. Show that $\mathring A=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:x_1\lt 0,x_2\gt 0\}$

First let define $B=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:x_1\lt 0,x_2\gt 0\}$ and $C=A\setminus B=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:x_1\lt 0,x_2=0\}$. Note that $A=B\cup C$. We're going to show that $\mathring A=B$

Let $x\in B$ and we define $\color{Blue}{\varepsilon=min(-x_1,x_2)\gt 0}$. Let's show that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$. For that, take $y\in B(x,\varepsilon)$, and we know that:
$$\color{Blue}{\Bigg(}\lvert{y_1-x_1}\rvert\le \lVert y-x\rVert\lt \varepsilon\text{  }\text{and}\text{ }\text{ }\lvert y_2-x_2\rvert\le \lVert y-x\rVert\lt \varepsilon\color{Blue}{\Bigg)}$$

By the definition of $\varepsilon$ we have that: $x_1\le -\varepsilon\lt y_1-x_1\lt\varepsilon\le -x_1$ and $-x_2\le -\varepsilon\lt y_2-x_2\lt\varepsilon\le x_2$

From that it follows that $\color{Blue}{y_1\lt 0}$ and $\color{Blue}{0\lt y_2}$, therefore $y\in A$. So every point in $B$ is an interior point, so that $B\subseteq \mathring A$. Let's see know no point of $C$ can bean interior point of $A$. If $x\in C$ and $\varepsilon\gt 0$ is arbitrary, we can define $y=(x_1,\varepsilon/2)$. And $y\in B(x,\varepsilon)$ y $y\notin A$. That means that for every $\varepsilon\gt 0$ we have that $B(x,\varepsilon)\nsubseteq A$. Therefore no point of $C$ is an interior point of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $B$ is the second quadrant on $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the vertical and horizontal axis, for a ball centered on a point of $B$ to be contained inside $B$, the ball must not "go over" any of the axis. You can think of it in a geometric manner: take any point on the second quadrant and draw a circle around it. That circle will be completely contained in the second quadrant unless it touches or crosses one of the axis.

Notice that by taking $x = (x_1,x_2) \in B$ and defining a ball with radius $\varepsilon = min(-x_1,x_2)$ around $x$, you ensure that no point inside this ball will cross any of the axis because the distances from $x$ to the horizontal and vertical axis are, respectively, $|x_1| = -x_1$ and $|x_2| = x_2$. The following picture might be able to show you this idea better.

[image: Ball centered on x with radius epsilon]

Now, for the things you marked in blue: inside the parenthesis, we have that $||y-x||<\varepsilon$ because of the fact that $y \in B(x,\varepsilon)$. For the other side of the inequalities, note the following:

$$|y_1 - x_1| = \sqrt{|y_1 - x_1|^2} \leqslant \sqrt{|y_1 - x_1|^2 + |y_2 - x_2|^2} = ||y-x||$$

By the same logic, you arrive at $|y_2 - x_2| \leqslant ||y-x|| < \varepsilon$.

Finally, to get the last inequalities in blue, use the results you obtained on the line above. From $x_1\le -\varepsilon\lt y_1-x_1\lt\varepsilon\le -x_1$ you have that $y_1-x_1 < -x_1$, and by adding $x_1$ to both sides you get $y_1 < -x_1 + x_1 = 0$. Once again, the same logic applies to $y_2$, and you can get the inequality in blue by adding $x_2$ to both sides in second result on the line above.